# How can I edit a Moneropedia definition or add a new one?

Tags: getmonero-website, moneropedia

The [Moneropedia](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/moneropedia/) page has some terms with very basic definitions. More concerning are the large number of important terms and definitions that are missing completely.

How can I help update [Moneropedia](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/moneropedia/)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Easy method:**

- Visit the [moneropedia page](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/moneropedia/)
- Use the [open issue](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site/issues) link at bottom of page
- Login to and/or create a GitHub account
- Click [new](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site/issues/new)
- Input the Moneropedia terms and defintions you would like to add or modify
- Click `submit new issue`
- Track your request [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site/issues)

**Edit an existing entry yourself method:**

- Visit the GitHub for the [monero website](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site)
- Login to GitHub
- Make a fork of the site
- Click `knowledge-base`
- Click `moneropedia`
- Click on the term you wish to edit
- Click `edit`
- Make your desired changes to the term definition, consistent with the existing format
- Click `create a new branch for this commit and start a pull request`
- Click `propose file change`
- track your [pull request](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site/pulls)

**Add a new entry yourself method:**

- Visit the GitHub for the [monero website](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site)
- Login to GitHub
- Make a fork of the site
- Click `knowledge-base`
- Click `moneropedia`
- Click `create new file`
- Create a new Moneropedia term and definition, consistent with the formatting for existing terms
- Click `create a new branch for this commit and start a pull request`
- Click `propose new file`
- track your [pull request](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site/pulls)

Comment: You could also click "[Edit This Page]" at the bottom of the entry you want to edit.